# How to back up notes taken with Samsung Notes app?

Tags: backup, samsung-notes

I'm using my Samsung Tab 2016 P580 for taking lecture notes. I used the Samsung Notes app, and now, my device is running out of storage. Furthermore, I can't access the notes from my PC.

I have a 32GB storage card that can't function as Internal storage. I am looking to back up my notes and I do not have a rooted device.

Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. How do you know your storage is full? Why and how you connect your device to PC? Is 32GB internal storage or external sd card? What does it mean by "can't function as an internal storage"? Are you talking about adaptable storage?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I got an alert from the system. Via usb. I have 16GB internal and 32GB in an sd card... Yes, it means I want to use it as an adoptable storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use other applications that allow synchronization with other devices via your account. So in this case nothing is stored in your local storage and you can also access your note from other devices(Just need to login to their service).

My recommendations are:

1. [Microsoft OneNote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.onenote&hl=en)
2. [Evernote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote)

Comment: Thanks but I need to backup my previous notes... For this, do you have any idea? I don't have root...

Answer (score 0):

Every version of Samsung Notes I have seen is completely lacking export functionality.

Unfortunately, without root, you have to manually cut and paste every note individually to another app.

It's a lesson I learned the hard way, and I now recommend avoiding Samsung apps and any apps they force-install on their devices.